# Create 3 VNETS where all traffic is routed through one VNET (hub and spoke)

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to figure out how to answer I question I recently had on an exam.  The requirements are as follows:

1. You plan on creating 100 VMs across 3 virtual networks (vnetA, vnetB, and vnetC)
2. All traffic must be routed through vnetA
3. All virtual machines must be able to talk to each other via private IP
4. Solution must not require any virtual gateways
5. Solution must minimize the number of peerings.
6. Solution must not require any network virtual appliance (VM acting as router)

To me, this sounds like a hub and spoke topology where I perform the following steps.

1. Create vnet peering from vnetA to vnetB (allow forwarded traffic)
2. Create vnet peering from vnetB to vnetA
3. Create vnet peering from vnetA to vnetC (allow forwarded traffic)
4. Create vnet peering from vnetC to vnetA

Now I need the spoke to spoke connectivity (between vnetB and vnetC) but it has to pass through vnetA which is where I get confused.  My first thought was to simply enable Allow gateway transit/Use remote gateways options between the two peerings above, but it doesn't allow that due to vnetA not having  virtual network gateway (I even tried adding a GatewaySubnet to vnetA).

I can't seem to use a custom route table attached to the subnets of vnetB and vnetC to specify a next hop unless I use a virtual appliance which can't be used in this solution.

Anyone have any ideas on how they would approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible to meet all the requirements 1-6. Since peering connections are non-transitive eventhough *Transitive network flow between peered vnets is on MS roadmap* from this feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/18772234-allow-transitive-network-flow-between-peered-vnet), you have to create VNet peering between VNetB and VNetC. But this method will add the number of peerings and traffic Between VNetB to VNetC will not be routed via VNetA.

After having a quick test, select **Allow forwarded traffic** is not enough. This configuration option is necessary when configuring virtual networking appliances within your hub VNet so that transit traffic can route through the hub. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#create-a-peering).

> **Allow forwarded traffic**: Check this box to allow traffic forwarded by
> a network virtual appliance in a virtual network (that didn't
> originate from the virtual network) to flow to this virtual network
> through a peering. For example, consider three virtual networks named
> Spoke1, Spoke2, and Hub. A peering exists between each spoke virtual
> network and the Hub virtual network, but peerings don't exist between
> the spoke virtual networks. A network virtual appliance is deployed in
> the Hub virtual network, and user-defined routes are applied to each
> spoke virtual network that route traffic between the subnets through
> the network virtual appliance. If this checkbox is not checked for the
> peering between each spoke virtual network and the hub virtual
> network, traffic doesn't flow between the spoke virtual networks
> because the hub is not forwarding the traffic between the virtual
> networks. While enabling this capability allows the forwarded traffic
> through the peering, it does not create any user-defined routes or
> network virtual appliances. User-defined routes and network virtual
> appliances are created separately. Learn about user-defined routes.
> You don't need to check this setting if traffic is forwarded between
> virtual networks through an Azure VPN Gateway.

To conclude, you have to create a VPN gateway for the hub-spoke network or use a virtual appliance as the hub and create UDR for the spoke network. Or simply create a peering between VNetB and VNetC.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured which is why I was so confused about the question.  The only way I know to make traffic flow through vnet A is if vnetA has a virtual network gateway or a virtual appliance.

Comment: I wonder why someone minus 1 the question.  Is that not appropriate to ask?

Comment: Maybe someone suggests asking a non-program question in server vault.

Comment: The exam question was hands-on correct? I guess the question is wrong and the correct implementation for the answer is to create the peerings, even if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path mate. This all needs to be ARM; when you peer VNET A and B, all you need to do is select "Allow virtual network access from VNET A/B = Enabled" for the peering between A and B and B and A. Then, for the peering between B and A only, select "Allow forwarded traffic from VNETA = Enabled". 

You don't need any peering between B and C.

Allow forwarded traffic means that traffic not originating from VNET A (so VNET C) is allowed to come into VNET B.

Repeat the same process between B and C. Then you'll have a hub and spoke design. Traffic from B will get to C via A. Because you're not traversing any traffic to ExpressRoute or a VPN or a classic VNET, you don't need any gateway.

Comment: Thanks for responding : )  I should have mentioned that the Allow virtual network access is defaulted to enabled which I didn't change so that part is configured like you mentioned.  I also have already configured the forwarded traffic setting to enabled for the two peerings that originate from vnetA so I'm not sure if I need to do anything else or I just misunderstood what you are saying.    The last thing you said is that I should repeat some process between vnetB and vnetC but I cannot create anything between them according to the requirements. ?

Comment: I think the requirement that can confuse is "Solution must minimize the number of peerings" which makes it seem like you need to do as little as possible. These exam questions are designed to do that. Do as many peerings as is required to complete the solution. In order to meet the requirement "All virtual machines must be able to talk to each other via private IP", you need peering between A and C.

Comment: I already had a peering between A and C bro.  Did you mean B and C?

Answer (score 0):

This requires Hub and Spoke Design:

1. Create VNET Peering between VNET A and VNET B
2. Create VNET Peering between VNET B and VNET A
3. Create VNET Peering between VNET C and VNET B
4. Create VNET Peering between VNET B and VNET C
5. Add a Subnet Gateway in VNET B
6. Allow Gateway Transit on VNET B -VNET A Peering
7. Allow Gateway Transit on VNET B -VNET C Peering
8. Create Virtual Network Gateway in VNET B
9. Create Routing Tables
10. Attach Routing Tables to VNET A and VNET B Subnets
11. Enable Remote Gateway on VNET A - VNET B Peering
12. Enable Remote Gateway on VNET C - VNET B Peering

Answer (score 0):

The question does not say that NVAs cannot be used, but any deployment of such would constitute you deploying a routing solution. The question explicitly states what you would do **before** configuring IP routing, and so the answer may not be as complicated as you expect.

You do not need a gateway subnet or virtual gateways to implement a hub and spoke topology assuming that you are going to provision, for example, a VM with IP Forwarding enabled on the vNIC to act as a router.

1. Create your 3 subnets, in your example vnetA, vnetB and vnetC
2. From vnetA, create a peering with VNETb using the Resource Manager Deployment Model
3. Ensure "Allow forwarded traffic from vnetA to vnetB" is enabled
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3, substituting vnetB for vnetC

And that's it. Now when you configure IP routing you will provision a router VM or some other Network Virtual Appliance (NVA) in the hub network and create a Route Table for later application to vnetB and vnetC specifying the router VM's internal IP as the next hop.